# Drop Down Menu Broke after SSL Install

Tags: jquery, ssl, drop-down-menu, weebly

After installing a SSL certificate on my Weebly built site my dropdown menus stopped working.

This version of my site works: http://www.backyardbeertours.ca

This version does not work: https://www.backyardbeertours.ca

When you navigate to the `Tours & Prices` menu item a dropdown menu with four items displays in the `http` site and does not display in the 'https' site.

In the `https` site the Error Console shows these messages:

```
[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://www.backyardbeertours.ca/tours--prices.html was not allowed to run insecure content from http://www3.dragndropbuilder.com/editor/libraries/fancybox/fancybox.css?1432850887. (tours--prices.html, line 37)

[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://www.backyardbeertours.ca/tours--prices.html was not allowed to run insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700. (tours--prices.html, line 39)

[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://www.backyardbeertours.ca/tours--prices.html was not allowed to run insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700. (tours--prices.html, line 40)

[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://www.backyardbeertours.ca/tours--prices.html was not allowed to run insecure content from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic. (tours--prices.html, line 41)

[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “assets.www3.dragndropbuilder.com” which could put your confidential information at risk. (sites.css, line 0)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Prototype
  (anonymous function) (tours--prices.html:70)
  Global Code (tours--prices.html:73)
[Error] Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “assets.www3.dragndropbuilder.com” which could put your confidential information at risk. (main.js, line 0)
```

Comment: Your site works exactly as you describe the desired behaviour. What OS are you using? What browser? Have you restarted the browser and ensured the caches have been purged so you are seeing the actual site and not some junk stuck in your browser cache? Or is this some odd attempt to advertise your site because, at the moment this post being closed as spam is a possible outcome. All in all I suggest a deep breath, count to 10 and do the 'is it plugged in?' steps and see if you really have a real problem or not.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I assure you this is not some strange way to advertise my very local business. However, the site is not working. I've tried over multiple OS's, and browsers. Make sure you're going to https://www.backyardbeertours.ca/ Compare this with http:// version. Look at the drop down menu in the http:// one. This is how it used to be, with 4 items dropping down. Now, go to the https:// version. You'll notice on the same menu item, there is no drop down menu. Also, if you look at the mobile version of the site, the menu items are showing outside of the menu selection box.

Comment: I didn't really think it was an ad. But you didn't share enough info to let us help you. I have edited your question to include the info you just shared in comments and I posted the messages from the error console that you should have posted. If you don't know how to get to the error console on your browser urgently browse for how to do that because you have to know if you are going to own a site. You should have included these in your question. None of this is intended to be mean, just trying to explain how to get the best and most out of SO. Do you understand how to address the messages?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've included that. Thank you so much for doing it for me. I've never really had to ask for help like this before. The google fonts I'm not worried about, but it must be the dragndropbuilder. However, when I add https:// to the dragndropbuilder link above, it says this in the error console: 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
https://assets.www3.dragndropbuilder.com/js/site/main.js?buildTime=1432850887 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

So I guess I'm not exactly sure what to change these links to, but I know how to make changes.

Comment: So the answer to your original question is "You are trying to include http (insecure) active content in your https (secure) site". Now you need to read up on this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content. If you have specific questions about what that suggests then I'd suggest a new specific question on that/those point/s.